# Why isn’t there an arithemetic Riemann Roch for closed immersions?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, arakelov-theory

I read Faltings’s works and Soule’s works on ARR and found that both of them proved this for proper maps which are smooth over Q. But GRR holds for arbitrary proper maps between smooth varieties, so I wonder what goes wrong in the arithmetic setting. (I know their proof does not work in the general case but does there exist a proof?)

Thanks!

Comment: There is: Gillet-Soulé, *An arithmetic Riemann-Roch theorem*, Invent. Math. 110 (1992), no. 3, 473-543.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This really solves my question!

Comment: Just want to point out that this is actually a really good question. For arithmetic purposes we would want to work with embeddings of the curve of genus $>2$ to P^n. So having ARR working for close immersions is important.